# What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?

Tags: lts, release-management

What are the differences between an Ubuntu Long Term Support release (LTS) and a normal release?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

There is a new release every 6 months (in April and October), with the version number being *year.month* (e.g.: 22.04 was released in April 2022). Every two years, the April release is a Long Term Support version.

- All **normal releases** (23.04 and later) are only supported for **9 months**.
- All **LTS releases** (22.04 and later) are supported for **five years** on both the desktop and the server.
  <sub>Older versions had slightly different support cycles, but they haven't been included as they're all unsupported now. See the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) for historical information.</sub>

Now, support means:

- Updates for potential security problems and bugs (not new versions of software)
- Availability of Commercial support contracts from Canonical
- Support by Landscape, Canonical's enterprise oriented server management tool set

**The *Desktop*** refers to the packages that are in the **main** and **restricted** repositories, these are the ones that have the little  Ubuntu icon next to them in Synaptic or are marked as Supported in the Software-Centre respectively.

**The *Server*** packages are the ones in the "server-ship" and "supported-common" *seeds* (there's a [directory of all of the different seeds](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/germinate-output/) available).

This is what this looks like:

[![Image showing ubuntu release plan and support]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFqar.png)

<sub>Image from [Ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life)</sub>

The primary reason for using an LTS release is that you can **depend on it** being updated regularly and therefore secure and stable.

As if this wasn't enough, Ubuntu releases additional versions of the last LTS between releases—such as **14.04.1**, that incorporate all of the updates up to this point. This is called a Point-Release (or sometimes *snapshot*). Those are released every quarter to half year, as needed.

In addition to support, there are Development strategies that differentiate an LTS release:

- The *base* of the operating system, Debian, comes in three versions: Stable, Testing and Unstable. Normally, Ubuntu is based on Unstable; the LTS releases are based on Testing. [Starting with 14.04 LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS), all new releases will be based on Debian *Unstable*.
- The Development effort for an LTS release in focused on providing a *rock solid* base, not only for customers who want the LTS release, but also for the next three Ubuntu versions to come.

---

Thanks to Oli for demystifying that last part, I wasn't quite sure about it.

Comment: Does it mean that every Ubuntu version has its own repositories?

Comment: @Olivier Yes they do

Comment: Why actually does Ubuntu base of Debian's Unstable and Testing for its normal and LTS releases (respectively) ?

Comment: This answer seems awfully confusing with a lot of before/after this ver., if this else that. Could historical information be removed for brevity?

Comment: @minerz029, I agree on it being complicated, but I would live it complete as long as 12.04 is still in the run.

Comment: @magu_: The historical info can all be removed.  12.04 is supported for five years on the desktop (the diagram needs 10.04 removing).

Comment: So, as I understand, apart the support lifecycle, the point release 18.04.3 LTS would have the same functionality and fixes in the 'Ubuntu' layer as 19.10, but be based on a more stable version of 'Debian'?

Answer (score 59):

The most important thing (for most people) is how long you get to use an install without having to do a release upgrade. A non-LTS version of Ubuntu only gets updates for 9 months from its release so to stay up-to-date —which is critically important— you need to upgrade twice a year; you need to upgrade through every Ubuntu version…

Conversely an Ubuntu LTS release is supported for 5 years and you can upgrade directly from LTS to LTS. This gives you long-lived, solid base to target and test on that makes it super-easy to release-upgrade when you decide to. It's therefore ideal for mass deployment, high-availability systems, and just people who don't like doing release-upgrades.

In the last two LTS versions, point-updates have also been made available to support newer hardware (it's a kernel, driver and X stack), which boosts the utility of the LTS versions over their lifespan. The original stacks are maintained too.

Most other applications won't jump versions, so it makes for a solid, predictable deployment.

In terms of the Ubuntu development process, Ubuntu pulls many of its packages from Debian. Debian has multiple versions too (stable, testing and unstable) that usually correlate with package age. The package pull for an LTS will favour the more stable Debian version. I'm certain there are exceptions to this.

There also is supposedly more focus on bug fixing for an LTS release. More people have a vested interest in the success of an LTS so I'd like to think more people test it pre-release.

Comment: Just for clarification, what is LTS+1, LTS+2, etc.?

Comment: @ClaySmalley the next version after the LTS release is called LTS+1 (also, the next version of ubuntu is sometimes called e.g. maverick+1 or ubuntu+1)

Comment: Excuse me, is there any statistics about how many people uses LTS and how many uses latest version, or any statistics that can show that?

Answer (score 4):

Previous desktop LTS releases were supported for **3 years**.

However, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS will be supported for **5 years** both for desktop and server releases.

Answer (score 3):

Canonical provides security updates for the LTS releases for 3 years on the desktop and 5 years for the server version. The normal release is only supported with updates for 18 months.

Comment: Also starting with 10.04 Ubuntu is based on Debian Testing for the LTS releases. (Though usually most of the software ends up being a bit newer at release time).

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, LTS releases introduce fewer new technologies than Normal releases, and replaces them with Long Term Support of the older, more time-tested technologies that have proven track records of working like said.