# Which should I recommend, 10.04 vs 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, software-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release)

I've been running 10.04 for a while now.  I use it for development purposes and recreation, and I love it.  My friend recently had to reformat his computer because he got a virus.  Naturally, he is looking to try out Ubuntu (instead of his Windows 7).My friend would only use this for recreation/writing papers/etc., and he is not that tech savy.

I am torn because I know 10.04 would be more stable for him, but the 11.04 desktop looks interesting.

From your experience, are new features in 11.04 worth the instability?  For you users of 11.04, how stable is it?  Does it have noticeable problems?

I know it's a matter of preference, so I'm searching for opinions.

Should I recommend 10.04 or 11.04?

Thanks for your responses!

Comment: This is subjective and speculative at best with no real means for an objective answer.

Answer (score 4):

I was on 10.04 for a year not transitioning to 10.10 even to try it out. Stability in 10.04 is rock solid as you say. But if a guy was coming from Win7 he'd probably like the Unity Shell in 11.04. It's awesome! I just moved to 11.04 three days back and I find it pretty much stable. If your friend does run into trouble with the Unity Interface, he can always fall back to the regular Gnome DE

Answer (score 1):

If it's a "legacy"(older) system I would try the 10.04 LTS version! For some reason 11.04 seems to be very "finicky" about what system it's installed on! I've noticed that the releases become more stable as the developers have time to fix the issues that crop up with the release.

Answer (score 0):

i have had nothing but trouble since upgrading from 10.04 to 11.04. it caused (or coincided with) massive hard drive failures -- multiple OS and DATA drives on separate machines, and i lost my NVIDIA graphics card in the mess (hardware failure).

one of my systems does not even allow me to "Save As ..." in any program, nor does it allow me the ability to upload to various key websites.

again -- it could be my hardware, or it could be the software, or it could be a combination. either way, it all started happening when i tried to run the Upgrade function.

Comment: I couldn't get 11.04 to run properly until I did a clean install! Had horrible problems when going the "upgrade" route!

Answer (score 0):

I personally found 10.04 to be much more stable as compared to 11.04. The latter strangely seems to hang every few days (forcing me to press Ctrl-Alt-F1 and do some command line-fu) and sometimes even logs me out automatically. So I'd definitely recommed 10.04 to a new, not-so-tech-savvy user.