# How will be the LTS support for Xubuntu after 3 years?

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, release-management

Hi :) I'm comfortable with Xubuntu 12.04 because I have an older computer, but I was reading about the LTS support:

- [Ubuntu 12.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases): **Supported until** april **2017**.
- [Xubuntu 12.04](http://xubuntu.org/help/): **Supported until** april **2015**.

I want a 5 years support, then my question is: **Will be those 3 years support just for XFCE packages or for all packages?** I want ask: After 3 years, will Xubuntu have updates for packages as Firefox, LibreOffice, kernel...?

If the answer is no (I suppose it), I could change the 'apt' repositories, from 'xubuntu' to 'ubuntu'. How do you see this solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The core aspects of Ubuntu get full support for the full period. That includes kernels, pre-installed applications. You should be fine with Firefox updates. It's the XFCE stuff that will start to lag behind.

The repositories for Xubuntu and Ubuntu are the same — it's just a different selection of packages. If you want full Xubuntu support indefinitely you either need to upgrade in a timely manner or maintain (or pay somebody else to maintain) all the packages you need indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks Oli! Then, in 4 years from now, will I have updates for all the system, except XFCE components? :)

Comment: Yes, you definitely will.