# Update manager doesn't offer an upgrade to the new release

Tags: upgrade, release-management, mirrors

So I have Ubuntu installed on my pc, and I want to upgrade to the new Ubuntu which was just released. When I check for any new updates it doesn't show any upgrades to the new release. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you read through this Q&A? http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04  especially the bit about software-sources etc.?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 i386, I tried all the above but to update I had to execute do-release-upgrade -d

Comment: As on today Aug 14 , I got notification on 16.04 to update it to 18.04.1

Answer (score 14):

If you're not getting an option to upgrade then your local mirror might be out of date, you can either wait a bit for that to resolve itself, or manually switch to another mirror. You should also make sure your software properties [settings are correct](https://askubuntu.com/a/125646/235).

- [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)

After that follow the upgrade instructions:

- [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Answer (score 11):

`do-release-upgrade` in terminal should work

Answer (score 10):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and paste: `gksu software-properties-gtk`.

Then go to tab "Updates" and at "Notify me about new Ubuntu version" choose "For any version".

[image: software source "Updates" tab for 11.10]

(Or if you are at 10.04, go to tab "Updates" and at "Release upgrade" choose "Normal Releases")

[image: software source "Updates" tab for 10.04]

Finally open Update Manager and check it again.

Reference: [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/110477/52923)

Answer (score 4):

In the Update Manager settings, make sure "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" is not set to "Never."

Answer (score 2):

You can select any of the Normal or LTS releases in the Release update setting.
After exit, reload.

You can then start update manager and click check.

One property of Ubuntu is unless you update all the packages to a desired version for the upgrade, option to upgrade will not appear.

so first, kindly apply all the updates of all the packages.
Then when you click update, this option of 12.04 should appear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

12.04 is a "Long-term support" version. By default it will only offer upgrades to the next LTS in a few years time.

To force it to offer upgrading to a normal release such as 12.10 you can open Software sources and set **Show new distribution releases** to **Normal releases**.

See this answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/125646/27968

Answer (score 0):

12.01 is less then 12.04. Meaning it's not an update. I assume you mean 12.10. Please update your question if that is the case.

12.04 is a LTS release. By default it only updates to the next LTS release (13.something a long time from now) You can change this by running `update-manager` from the terminal and clicking settings. On the "Updates" tab select Notify me "For any new version". Then close the window.

Run `update-manager` again and you should get a little popup for the upgrade.

Make sure this is what you want to do though. For most casual users, 12.04 is recommended (and is the latest).

Comment: Thank you..it is offering now. Yes i meant 12.10. Sorry :( If i goto 12.10 would it messup my LTS or is it safe?

Comment: LTS is "Safer" [see this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release) 12.10 is totally fine, but LTS version usually have fewer issues then non-LTS versions. The price for that is the fact that LTS versions don't always run the latest versions of software.

Comment: OK i understand now. I guess i can clone my vdi and try the 12.10 update on the clone. This is for home/fun use. Thank you for helping so fast :)