# Why don't I see an option to upgrade to 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update manager doesn't offer an upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125612/update-manager-doesnt-offer-an-upgrade-from-11-10-to-12-04)

Looking to upgrade 11.10 to 12.04, update manager doesn't display the Install button after fully updating everything available. Should I download to cd/usb and install from there or is there a fix? I am running a dual-boot system (windows 7 on the other half), 32-bit acer machine.

Answer (score 6):

The first place I would look is at Update-Manager's settings.

1. Open Update-Manager. In the lower-left corner should be a `Settings...` button. Open it.
2. The `Software Sources` window (below) should open. Select the `Updates` tab.
   [image: Software Sources image for 11.10]
3. At the bottom  `Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:` should be set to `For any new version`. If it is not, then change it.
4. If you changed the setting then save and close the window and see if the upgrade  to 12.04 notice  now appears.

If that did not work, then I suggest trying one of the other methods discussed in
[**How do I upgrade from 10.04 or 11.10 to 12.04?**](https://askubuntu.com/q/110477/52923)

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade dialog will tell you to upgrade to 11.10 first.  Once you've upgraded to 11.10, the upgrade dialog will then tell you to upgrade to 12.04.  It will probably be faster to take a backup of your existing data and create a Live USB to clean install from.  You can follow the links on the right side of the page here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/try-ubuntu-before-you-install

There are instructions for Windows, Ubuntu and OSX on creating a bootable USB.