# How can I resume an upgrade after denying it the first time?

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

Last evening i started the procedure to upgrade ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 while not being at home and with a slow connection. During the upgrade procedure ubuntu told me that the required time with my connection  was very long. Because of lack of time i decided to deny the upgrade and start it today, but today i can't find how to start it again because the upgrade button is not anymore visible !

What can i do to upgrade ubuntu without downloading the iso?
Is there any terminal command that allow me to start the upgrade ?

Comment: It would help to have more information on where in the upgrade process your Ubuntu thinks it is at. Could you please issue the command `cat /etc/lsb-release` in a terminal window and add the output to your question by editing it? (Please, as recommended in the [faq#howtoask], do **not** use a comment to respond.)

Answer (score 3):

Start update manager and there you will find a button so you can upgrade. [image]

If not you need to enable update manager to look for dist upgrades see: [Update manager doesn't offer an upgrade to the new release](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125612/update-manager-doesnt-offer-an-upgrade-from-11-10-to-12-04)

Answer (score 2):

Type this in Terminal

```
 update-manager -d
```

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Alt<kbd>+</kbd>F2</kbd> and type `update-manager -d` then click on Update Manager then I was able to see update to 11.10. Hope your problem will also be solved by this.