# Distribution upgrade at a chosen moment

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

When the window poped up that told me that 13.04 was released, I clicked on "Install later". Right now, I have got the time to upgrade but I can't find a button where to do it. It used to be in the update manager in previous versions but it has gone. Where can I dist-upgrade manually?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. My update manager says: Everything's up to date. The button mentioned here (http://askubuntu.com/a/129975/69748) isn't there any more in 12.10.

Comment: I don't know why, but I kept trying and update-manager -d now works where it hadn't before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update-manager -d
```

Accept all updates, it'll reload, and it'll tell you there is a new release.