# Problems Encountered While Updating From 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update manager doesn't offer an upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125612/update-manager-doesnt-offer-an-upgrade-from-11-10-to-12-04)

I am a Ubuntu 11.10 user and my update manager doesn't show the availability of the new 12.04 release. What should I do in order to upgrade my system?

Answer (score 0):

Run do-release-upgrade in a terminal

Check here! 
This links describes how to upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04.

[How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04)