# Ubuntu 12.04 update manager not offering 12.10 upgrade

Tags: 12.04, update-manager, stable-release-updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update manager doesn’t offer an upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125612/update-manager-doesnt-offer-an-upgrade-from-11-10-to-12-04)

i have 12.04 with all updates applied as of 11-17-12. Re-ran update manager and it does
not offer 12.10 to me. I am doing this in virtualbox latest version. is this the reason? If not how to get update manager to offer me 12.10? thx :)