# How to upgrade from Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 beta 2 to 14.04 LTS final release?

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 14.04

Currently I have Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 beta2 release. But in details it shows as Ubuntu 13.10. Please let me know how can I upgrade it 10 14.04 LTS final release(released 17th April). 
I tried in update-manager, but still it is not listing the new version.

Comment: I just tried that but there's no updates yet.
Do I need to add another LTS repo or something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update manager doesn't offer an upgrade to the new release](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125612/update-manager-doesnt-offer-an-upgrade-to-the-new-release)

Comment: Your title says you are on 14.04 beta but in the body you mention you are on 13.10. Which version of ubuntu are you on? You can confirm the version by typing `lsb_release -a` on a terminal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 shows 13.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449458/ubuntu-gnome-14-04-shows-13-10)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything apart from `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` or simply wait until the new updates appear on the Update Manager. This will simply move your Beta 2 version to the final release. No need to download the ISO, reinstall everything or need to format.

So hold on a bit until Update Manager shows the new packages or do an:

```
apt-get update

apt-get upgrade
```

And reboot. Enjoy 14.04 Final.

Comment: I think that here is another problem: [Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 still shows 13.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449458/ubuntu-gnome-14-04-shows-13-10/449475#449475). And the reboot is unnecessary.

Comment: The reboot could be necessary if one of the updated packages is the kernel. For the 14.04 showing 13.10 that is a normal minor bug. It just means that the piece that holds the version was not updated. I suspect in the following days he will get a small update that fixes that.