# Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 shows 13.10

Tags: gnome, versions

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 and when I open "Details" it shows 13.10. In "Software & Updates" it shows 14.04 and all the repos are "trusty".

[image: ubuntu version]

I installed 14.04 when it just became a beta if that makes any difference. Everything is up to date.

Is this just me or is this a bug?

Comment: I faced the same issue [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/455823/command-line-shows-ubuntu-version-as-14-04-while-gui-shows-13-10)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was a mistake by Ubuntu GNOME Team, they will patch it as soon as possible. No need to worry, this has already been
[reported on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1299912). You can have look at the
[Google+ Announcement](https://plus.google.com/108356762331170101188/posts/CtoVGJ5ze1b).

Quoting the official Ubuntu GNOME Page:

> Ubuntu GNOME Team is aware of this issue. It was too late, due to the final freeze, to change that.
>
> This will be changed right after the final release of Ubuntu GNOME
>   14.04 LTS and it should end up with the GNOME Logo and "Version 3.10" :)
>
> Thank you!

**Update: 10th May** This issue has been fixed. Take a look at [Comment #11 of bugreport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1299912/comments/11)