# Xubuntu 14.04 Software Updater not finding any updates?

Tags: xfce

recently installed `Xubuntu`, and upgraded to 14.04 earlier today. When I use Software Updater to search for updates it tells me there are no updates available. Here's what I did in terminal:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
atp-get dist-upgrade (no problems so far)
```

restarted laptop

```
sudo -i   
update-manager -d
```

At this point I get this warning:

```
root:estimate_kernel_size_in_boot() returned '0'?
```

It then continues and opens Software Updater, which tells me the system is fully up to date. How do I fix this?

EDIT: To clarify, I'm using version `14.04` right now, I'm trying to upgrade to version `14.10`, and then to `15.04`

Comment: If you upgraded earlier _today_, why do expect there to be updates? Did `apt-get update` download the package lists alright, or were there errors?

Comment: I upgraded to version 14.04. So Im looking for 14.10, so I can then upgrade to 15.04.

Comment: 14.10 is no longer supported, you won't be able to upgrade to it.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why It doesn't show any updates. The latest version is 15.04, shouldn't I be able to update to that If 14.10 is no longer an option?

Comment: @Roland have you tried the second answer there? http://askubuntu.com/a/125646/158442

Comment: @muru yes, I was given a message telling me I didn't have permission to do that. I started another question asking about it but no one was able to help me so I just completely reinstalled ubuntu and everything works fine now

Answer (score 0):

Go into System Settings -> Software & Updates -> and navigate to the tab where it asks you if you want all versions of Ubuntu or just stable ones then change it to all, and then do a `sudo update-manager -d`

Comment: Nothing i try to change in software & updates changes, check boxes flash a blue check then disappear, etc. but the revert option pops up after i do something. When closing it I get a message saying the information about available software is out of date, then i get an error saying I am not allowed to perform this action. 

org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name': ':1.37'}): org.debian.apt.update-cache