# How to update form 10.10 to any supported version

Tags: updates

I'm trying to update from 10.10. This has become a problem for me. After typing

```
 update-manager -d
```

I get the following screen.[image]

Thereafter I try to update the usual way and get this pair of messages:[image] and [image]

After the last message, the update process automatically closes.

*Can somebody help me either by pointing out what's preventing me from upgrading or how not to update to 11.04 but to 12.04 or 12.10 directly?*

Comment: New questions about [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) Ubuntu releases are considered off-topic as per [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq). These old releases are unsupported and their use is not recommended. They don't even get updates for newly discovered security vulnerabilities, which makes using them risky. If you install or upgrade to [a supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable) and this question still applies, please flag and/or comment to request it be reopened.

Comment: @Jorge You can download a new ISO, create a LiveCD or a [LiveUSB](http://askubuntu.com/q/26269/62483) and install Ubuntu from there.

Comment: @vasa1 I think we should not consider this off-topic, if the goal is to get to a supported release. We support upgrading to non-EoL releases, so we should support updating to an EoL release when it's necessary as an intermediate step for upgrading to a non-EoL release. Presumably this user is using Ubuntu 10.10, also EoL. The only way to upgrade 10.10 to a supported release is through 11.04 (10.10 -> 11.04 -> 11.10). **Jorge Campos**: Have you enabled the `old-releases` repositories, as [explained here](http://askubuntu.com/q/91815)? If it still fails, what happens if you disable `extras`?

Comment: What are your PC specs?

Comment: @Jorge - please follow the advice in the duplicate Q&A now in your question.  You'll need to do this twice - once to get to 11.04.  Then, change your repositories again to old-releases to get to 11.10.  Then you should upgrade normally to 12.04.  You cannot upgrade directly to 12.04 - you can only do so via a complete reinstall.

Comment: Please read this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/168939/why-does-ubuntu-only-support-versions-for-a-limited-time-and-what-does-it-mean/169078#169078

Comment: @Lucio thanks. The specs are: it's a laptop VAIO, Intel Core i3, 2.13 GHz, RAM:  3.0 GB, 64 bits.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Have you seen the duplicate above? http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release

Answer (score 0):

It is better for you to upgrade your ubuntu version. Either download a new version iso image and install using it, or run the command

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

It will automatically upgrade your system by downloading packages.

Comment: Actually, it depends on the case. It would be unwise to recommend somebody to upgrade right now from 10.10 to 12.10 because they will face the fact that the following version (11.04 for users with 10.10) is not supported anymore. For that case I would rather tell the user to download the newest ISO and in the live session tell it to upgrade the system. It would save the user a lot of download time and any problem found between version upgrades.

Comment: Oh! That's the best idea. I didn't think that much.