# Ubuntu 14.10 Lifespan

Tags: updates, 14.10

Ubuntu 14.10 will be supported for 9 months for Ubuntu Desktop. So what will happen after 9months? It will not be updated and supported anymore? Can someone explain more in detail ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 9 months, Canonical expects you will have upgraded to 15.04 and they will not be making new patches or security updates.  For the long term support (for those who don't want to upgrade every 6 months) try Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Currently I am using Ubuntu 10.04 real time, unfortunately it has a WiFi issue, after 30 min it disconnected. I searched in the forums and found some comments talking about the same issue. That's why I'm trying to move on to the next generation of ubuntu ,and it seems like the problems have been solved in this generation.

Comment: 10.04 Desktop is no longer supported either. You should upgrade to 12.04 at least. You might then want to upgrade to 14.04 which is the latest LTS release. And from there, to 14.10, if you wish to switch to the non-LTS releases.

Comment: Great, I am glad the upgrade helped!  If you want a more detailed explanation, see Stefano Palazzo's answer at http://askubuntu.com/a/16370/196326

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/168939/why-does-ubuntu-only-support-versions-for-a-limited-time-and-what-does-it-mean/169078#169078