# Update Lubuntu 14.04 to 14.10

Tags: upgrade, updates, lubuntu

I installed Lubuntu 14.04 LTS from a disc. How do I get 14.10? Will installing updates effectively provide this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some important notes:

- Lubuntu 12.04 is an LTS (Long Term Support) release, it will be supported till April, 2019. Lubuntu 14.10 is a normal release and its support will end in July, 2015. So, unless you have a very good reason you should stick with 14.04 LTS. Also check [Ubuntu release cycle insights](https://askubuntu.com/q/168939).
- Lubuntu 15.04 has been release this month, this one will be [supported till January, 2016](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_Ubuntu_releases&action=edit&section=28). Now you might be interested in upgrading directly from 14.04 to 15.04, but this is not possible. Al first you have to upgrade to 14.10 and then to 15.04 or you can do a backup of all your data and then install 15.04 directly from disc. Again sticking with Lubuntu 14.04 might be the best option for you.

---

Knowing all that if you still want to upgrade from Lubuntu 14.04 to 14.10, do the following:

- At first you need to confirm that `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`  file has the following line:

  ```
  Prompt=normal
  ```

  If `Prompt` has any other value e.g. `lts` or `never`, change it to `Prompt=normal`.
- Now you can run the following command to upgrade your Lubuntu 14.04 to Lubuntu 14.10:

  ```
  sudo do-release-upgrade
  ```

Also check out the [general release up-gradation thread](https://askubuntu.com/q/110477/216503).

Answer (score 0):

You can run the system upgrade command `do-release-upgrade` as root `sudo do-release-upgrade`