# Support for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, support

Where can I find the official support policies for Ubuntu versions? Need to know, until when 20.04 will be supported and details around this.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Ironically, sometimes reading the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) help page suggested on the *"Ask a question"* page comes in handy!  This is actually addressed there under, *"Using and administering [currently supported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), official Ubuntu flavors"*! ;-)

Comment: Also see - [Why does Ubuntu only support versions for a limited time (and what does it mean)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168939/why-does-ubuntu-only-support-versions-for-a-limited-time-and-what-does-it-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple rule is -

LTS versions on Ubuntu are fully supported for 5 years after release (ie 20.04 LTS will be supported until April 2025).

Following the 5 years of standard support, you can get another 5 years of extended security maintenance.

The full details are available from Canonical: https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle