# How can I create a LiveCD/LiveDVD/LiveUSB?

Tags: installation, live-usb, live-cd, livedvd

How can I create a Ubuntu LiveCD/LiveDVD/LiveUSB?

Answer (score 9):

The image you can download from the [Ubuntu website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) already is a live-CD waiting to be burned, you can burn it by following the instructions which can also be found on the [download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop):

- [Burning a CD in Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-windows)
- [Burning a CD in Mac OSX](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-mac-osx)
- [Burning a CD in Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-ubuntu)

The resulting CD will be your live-CD.

Comment: Maybe this is stupid to note, but also please make sure you actually have a CD/DVD burner. Not all disc drives can write to discs.

Answer (score 8):

To burn a LiveCD, LiveDVD or LiveUSB follow this steps:

1. Visit http://www.ubuntu.com
2. Go to: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/
3. Depending on your need (Server, Desktop, Cloud) you will choose between:

   - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop
   - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server
   - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud
4. On each of the options above you can choose to either go for the LTS (Long Term Support) option or go with the latest one. The differences are mentioned in [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release)
5. After selecting the version of Ubuntu you want, you can choose to either get the 32 Bit version, 64 Bit Version. The differences are mentioned in [What are the differences between 32-bit and 64-bit, and which should I choose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)
6. There will be a A BIG button to download which will say **Get UBUNTU** and the version of Ubuntu available. Click on it and your download image (ISO Image) should appear and start downloading right away. After finishing the download we then have to select how we will burn the image.

   - If you are in Windows follow the [HOW TO GUIDE FOR WINDOWS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) to burn the image in Windows.
   - If you are in Mac follow the [HOW TO GUIDE FOR MAC](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-dvd-on-mac-osx) to burn the image in Mac.
   - If you are in Ubuntu follow the [HOW TO GUIDE FOR UBUNTU](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu) to burn the image in Ubuntu.
7. If you have done any of the **GUIDES** you should have a working LiveCD / LiveDVD image of Ubuntu to start installing and enjoying Ubuntu right away. But if you want to do the same but with a LiveUSB in Ubuntu then do the following steps:

   - With the image already downloaded, Open DASH and type **Disk Creator**

   [image]

   - Open **Startup Disk Creator**

   [image]

   - Click on the **Other** Button to select the image you want to burn to your USB Device. Search and select the image you want

   [image]

   - If you haven't already, connect the USB Device you wish to use as a LiveUSB installer

   [image]

   - You can either delete the partition (Erase it) or use an empty one. In this case I have a partitioned USB Drive. Select any partition or USB Drive that has at least 1GB of space since the image is about 700MB / 800MB in size. After which click on **Make Startup Disk**.
   - The option **Stored in Reserved Extra Space** is for when you want to use the LiveUSB as a bootable OS which means you will connect to the Internet with it, will do Documents with it, download music, videos, etc.. They will all be stored in a space reserved for them. You can tell the Disk Creator how much space you want to reserve for this.

Answer (score 4):

For a live USB use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), it is a cross-platform application that allows you to create bootable USB sticks (without even formatting your Flashdrive)

[image: Unetbootin - From their Website]

[image: Unetbootin - From their Website]

Answer (score 0):

You can put the image on a cd/dvd by burning the iso onto the optical disc you want to use. This can be done by different methods in different operating systems.

Windows: Right click the iso file and select "Burn image to disc".

Mac: Same as Windows.

Ubuntu: Use Brasero Disc Burner.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In Ubuntu, you right-click and select "Write to disc".