# reallocating free space from one partition to another

Tags: partitioning

Im running ubuntu oneiric server edition. The computer has 2 hard drives. On my storage drive I have 2 partitions both are ext4 and I'm trying to reallocate space from a larger one to a smaller one without rebooting. This is what the second storage drive looks like.

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   110102527    55050240   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2       110102528   976773167   433335320    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5       110104576   120590335     5242880   83  Linux
/dev/sdb6       120592384   976773167   428090392   83  Linux
```

How do I safely reallocate free space from /dev/sdb6 to /dev/sdb1 without using a boot cd?

EDIT:

This is a secondary drive so I can unmount it if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I do not believe you can resize/modify a partition that is currently in use. Your best bet would likely be using an Ubuntu live cd/usb to do this. I don't believe there is a solution that will not require rebooting your PC.

This link may be helpful for re-sizing the partitions from a live cd

http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/

This thread can help you make a live cd/usb [How can I create a LiveCD/LiveDVD/LiveUSB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172570/how-to-create-a-livecd-livedvd-liveusb)