# Is there anyway to run Ubuntu only when a cd is in my computer

Tags: windows

I am fairly new to modern linux. I would like to know if its possible to put Ubuntu on a cd or dvd then load it on my computer. However I want it so if i take out the cd/dvd from the drive it will boot normal windows 7. Is this possible

-Thanks

Comment: This is the default behavior of a Live session. I suggest to read the following links and create a Live USB with persistence space. 1)[How to create a LiveCD/DVD/USB](http://askubuntu.com/questions/172570/how-to-create-a-livecd-livedvd-liveusb), 2)[LiveUsbPendrivePersistent](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is what a live CD is for . You can not save data between sessions unless you make a USB with persistence or save data to a location on the hard drive.

> A live CD can be used for a quick demo or test of Ubuntu. Try Ubuntu without any changes to your machine! Windows or whatever you use normally is unaffected after trying this and then rebooting.

See : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD

If you like the demo, I suggest you go ahead and install.

If you have old hardware, Unity may be slow, consider xubuntu, kubuntu, or lubuntu.