# How do I check the quality of a download Ubuntu iso?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I have downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 from its official website. I've had problem installing it on my PC. Now I want to check whether my download was good or not as it took a long time to download .iso file. If the download isn't the problem, this would mean something else went wrong here and it would save me 6 hours of downloading this again.

I have  no technical knowledge, so is there any simple way that I can understand?

Now i have checked hash for the iso file and it doesnt matches, how can i repair it? any app is there to help me? as i have no knowledge for using codes or understanding them, what now? don't know what to do.

i have no linux os in my pc. so i can't use the terminal to download ubuntu. can i use terminal using livecd demo?  but using livecd demo slows my pc. how can i get a good download in windows?  any other suggestion ?

Comment: How did you try to install it? Please add more details on what you did during the installation process.

Comment: I burned image on a DVD using Nero.

Comment: Where did you get stuck during the installation? Please update your question with accurate and specific details.

Comment: I burned image on a DVD using Nero, then booted on bios.
everything when fine I set the time , place and everything went fine.
then when it started coping the file it showed error. I have tried many time to reinstall Ubuntu but in vain

Comment: Ever consider the possibility that it may be a bad disk? Try burning another disk, or look up how to make a bootable USB as those tend to be a _bit_ more reliable.

Comment: @BabuAtluru then you have to download it again. I recommend you download it via `wget -c "paste the .iso link here"` in Terminal

Comment: @kasiya : thanks, but i have no linux os in my pc. so i can't use the terminal. can i do it using livecd demo? it works ! but using it slows my pc. how can i get a good download in windows? or else any other idea ?

Comment: Use IDM on windows. And also why you don't use USB flash drive instead of burning it on a DVD?

Comment: @KasiyA: yes I have to consider about USB flash drive, but is there any difference using dvd vs usb drive?  I used nero, is that a good image burning tool? or should I try other software? thanks for your time. have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks. Also see [How can I create a LiveCD/LiveDVD/LiveUSB?](http://askubuntu.com/q/172570/283843)

Comment: @BabuAtluru there is no difference between using a DVD or flash drive - however, you will need to check that your machine can boot from a flash drive (it should be able to) - more details at KasiyA's link (above)