# I can't boot on the USB Stick and I have the ubuntu termminal display issue

Tags: boot, command-line, bios

If you look at this post ([When I start the computer, it only shows the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/600546/when-i-start-the-computer-it-only-shows-the-terminal/775705#775705?newreg=0b79a39c48334ab6b7d0edbdb532e05a)), it clearly describes my actual problem.
I have a computer on which ubuntu boots directly to the ubuntu terminal display and if I want to go to the BIOS by pressing F2 I have to enter a password which I don't know of.

I've tried those commands:

```
sudo service lightdm restart

startx
```

I even tried the method described in this post:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/616001/cant-access-to-ubuntu-interface-when-i-open-ubuntu-just-terminal-inteface

But neither of those methods worked and I'm stuck here.

Do you know which other solution there is for my problem? Or am I stuck with finding the BIOS password?

Thank you a lot everyone for your help.

Comment: Please tell us more details of your particular situation: 1. computer brand name and model; 2. graphics chip/card brand name and model; 3. version and flavour of Ubuntu (for example Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.3 LTS or Lubuntu 23.10); 3. Method and tool to create the USB boot drive (as many details as possible. -- Please edit your original question to add these details, and you will help us help you.