# How to resize the partition in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, gparted

I have only one partition right now. I want to make two partitions. But I am unable to do so. I am using `GParted` for this. Here is the `screenshot` of `gparted`.

[image]

When I click on resize. The minimum amount is always 0.

[image]

Comment: You need to boot from Ubuntu LiveCD.

Answer (score 1):

You currently are using the whole disk/partition.
First unmount the mounted partition `/dev/sda1`.

If you try this on a running system, it won't work.
Boot from ubuntu install media and open GParted.

Type in the new size and 'free space' will change.

Comment: You do not need unallocated space to split a partition.

Comment: It is still wrong. The problem is that the partition is in use.

Comment: Now it is OK. Undownvoted. But it was already answered long ago.

Answer (score 0):

As @Pilot6 says, that is because you can not resize the partition you are currently using (where your Ubuntu and Gparted are installed).

You will need to create a [Ubuntu Live CD/USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172570/how-can-i-create-a-livecd-livedvd-liveusb) where you will be able to run pre-installed Gparted and resize your partition.

Comment: do I have to install the ubunutu again...

Comment: No no simply run gparted from your live USB :) Refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) please

Comment: Ok let me try this one..hope it works...Is their any chance of losing my current OS?

Comment: There is always a chance. E.G. if you delete the partition.