# To Upgrade or not upgrade?

Tags: upgrade

Replaced Win XP on my old desktop with 14.04 which is working fine, should I upgrade to 15.0 - I'm not a programmer, just a basic user - what do I need to know before making the upgrade? Do I just download and instal 15.0 or do I need to uninstall 14.04 first? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Its advisable that you keep on using 14.04 as it is a lts version and thus is supported widely compared to other releases.

Comment: Also for the other question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend to upgrade if you're satisfied with your current 14.04 LTS system. Also you can make an [Ubuntu LiveUSB](https://askubuntu.com/q/287064/300458) (or [LiveDVD](https://askubuntu.com/q/172570/300458)) to test the new release and then make a decision.