# How to install ubuntu and remove windows 10

Tags: uninstall

How do I go about and remove the windows 10 os and install the Linux Ubuntu os.
I need to know what to do and what not to do. I tried to install Ubuntu along side of my windows 10 os and deleted my MBR files for windows 10 when I tried to remove the Ubuntu installation from the computer. I tried to install linux ubuntu today but was halted by too many problems on the pc was that upon booting from the usb it came to the menu do you want to try Ubuntu install Ubuntu and a couple of others I need help installing this because when I go to install it just shows the language, and then I follow the steps up to the how do I want to install it, however I get do you want delete disk and all files or do I want to install it a long side the windows boot loader. What am I doing wrong. I know have to re-transform my usb flash drive back to one that can boot with Ubuntu. What version of Ubuntu should I download if I have a 1ghz cpu and a 2gb ram card and a hard drive of about 300 gigs

Comment: Short answer (as a comment, since there are instructions in the linked question) there is an option to replace Windows in the installation process.

Comment: It's most likely you didn't erase the Windows bootloader, but you have let GRUB (Ubuntu's bootloader) to lead the boot process. Which, in fact, is a good thing, because GRUB recognizes the Win bootloader, but Win doesn't recognize GRUB. You can still use your Windows after you repair/update GRUB (for adding Win boot option to GRUB).

Comment: Good point, the OP can probably restore Windows with bootrec - should find information on that on superuser.com. Assuming he wants to keep Windows.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We're sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Start a Live Ubuntu, open GParted, delete all Windows partitions (recovery, oem, microsoft-reserved, installed-Windows partition). You can keep the EFI partition as it is needed for any operating system installed on uefi hardware. You can actually delete the EFI partition, but it will be (re)created during the install process of any OS on uefi hardware. Apply changes, close GParted and click the 'Install Ubuntu' icon. Let Ubuntu do its' install thing and you're done.

Comment: How do I do this. Do I need to use UNetbootin to create a bootable usb drive. Any step by step help would be great.

Comment: You can find detailed procedures here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/172570/how-can-i-create-a-livecd-livedvd-liveusb.

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)