# What are the Major Differences between Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10 in terms of Security?

Tags: security

I use Ubuntu 12.04. Recently, 12.10 was released. I'd like to upgrade but I want know what the benefits are in using Ubuntu 12.10 over Ubuntu 12.04 first.

My requirement is here Security , is there any security difference existed between Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 12.10 ? How best I can protect my PC ?

Comment: I would say wait a week or so and then see what other users are reporting. It's too early to tell how 12.04 and 12.10 differ in terms of performance.

Comment: @Glutanimate I think they were ready  before release  . because testing done right . I am not with testing so i dont know .thats why asking here .

Comment: hmm great one more close will ......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see some benchmarks [here](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu_1210_i5pre&num=1) comparing performance between 12.04 and 12.10. The majority of tests show no difference in terms of computational performance.

As with all benchmarks, there are many caveats:

- It only tests one hardware combination. Your results may vary.
- It is based on a pre-release version of 12.10 (although it is unlikely much has changed).
- "Bare metal" computational performance is not the same as user interface responsiveness. As observed above, anecdotal evidence claims that the performance of the Unity interface has regressed, but I cannot find any actual quantification of this.

Answer (score 6):

If your definition of working performance includes having a stable system, then a difference to keep in mind is that Ubuntu 12.04 is Long Term Service (LTS) release, whereas 12.10 is not.

A LTS release is targeted at running stable, whereas the others could be more experimental. It is less likely for a LTS to introduce a change that could break your system. Furthermore, you can upgrade a LTS release to the next LTS release, but for each intermediate release you have to upgrade to the next version.

For further reference, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release).

Answer (score 1):

it is slower (but trust me this problem will not be remain) on the other hand, there are several new features on it, especially in notification bar (top right of Unity desktop). Also there are several new features in Unity Interface. so I think it is better to use latest released Ubuntu because this OS is for smart and cutting edge people. ;D

Slower, to be precise is when it comes to loading the desktop from the login screen onwards. The booting of the OS is still as fast as it always used to promise. But it takes a little longer than 12.04 to load the unity DE.

Comment: I'm hearing a lot of anecdotal evidence that 12.10 is slower, but nobody has yet volunteered to explain what exactly is slower.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: yupe, i use it now, it is too slow in startup (fast startup is really important for me). also sometimes dash menu load searched items slower. so i just use Ubuntu 12.10 because it is new, and i really like to test latest Ubuntu, no more reason!