# Why upgrade from LTS to a X.10 version

Tags: upgrade, lts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release)

recently in an OMGubuntu's article i saw some comments about the reason of the selection of ubuntu 12.10 over 12.04 LTS for the new System76's All in One. One of the comments said more or less "Why using 12.10 with 1.5 years of support over the 5 years the LTS offer?". Until now i thought the X.10 version was more complete, but with this point of view of the LTS, the LTS will in some moment be more complete than 12.10 i guess.

Should i stick with the LTS or upgrade to 12.10 and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a questions of personal preference.

The non-LTS releases which also consist of some .04 releases have shorter periods of support, but often have 'new' features that the LTS releases do not.

For me I usually update myself to the latest on my personal primary laptop, go to testing on my testing laptop and depending on the features stay on the LTS for servers. For my work laptop I usually upgrade to the most recent, but I do not always have time to do it immediately upon release.

In summary:

If you want stability and want long term support then go with an LTS

If you want cutting edge, but still stable, go with the latest release