# Should I install 12.10 or 12.04.1?

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the difference between 12.04.1 and 12.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217184/whats-the-difference-between-12-04-1-and-12-10)

I am extremely new to Ubuntu and was shown by a friend. I am tired of paying for programs, that I have to fight with to get the results I want. I am also sick of paying for them. I really like the Ubuntu mind set. I am going to school for computer programming, but do not know a whole lot as of yet. I'm just looking for pointers, software to download to help teach me programming, and lastly which Ubuntu to go with as a beginner?

Thank you ahead of time for your help.

Comment: @Aditya Many if not most of the differences between 12.04 and 12.10 aren't just that one is an LTS and the other is a normal release. So it's probably best this has been closed as a duplicate of [that question about those two versions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/217184/whats-the-difference-between-12-04-1-and-12-10). However, you may want to see what questions we have, and if we don't have a good question explaining normal vs. LTS, you may want to ask (and perhaps also) answer a new one about that.