# Which is more stable ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10

Which version of ubuntu .04 or .10 is stable? I have heard that always the .10 versions are stable than .04 versions. Is it true? In home I am using 12.04 but in office I am uisng 12.10 version. I don't find a huge difference in stability. Please guide me.

Comment: Flagged as a duplicate a several other questions. Have a look at [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release) or [What's the difference between 12.04 and 12.10?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/217184/whats-the-difference-between-12-04-and-12-10)

Answer (score 1):

The stability should be pretty good on either version, although I have found 12.04 to be a little better.

In answer to the question about .10 versions being more stable than .04 versions: This is totally false. The only difference between versions is related to whether they are LTS(Long Term Support) or not. In this case, 12.04 is LTS and 12.10 is not.