# Ubuntu in Windows 8

Tags: installation, windows

Do I need to install a specific version of Ubuntu to run it alongside my Windows 8? I've downloaded the typical version.

Answer (score 1):

Install **Ubuntu 12.10**. Since Ubuntu 12.10, there's support for Secure Boot as the ISO is firmed and you'll be allowed to boot from it by default. The installer also supports **UEFI**, as far as I know.

Of course you can also install Ubuntu 12.04.2, but you'll have to disable Secure Boot from your BIOS configuration (if you're able to) and **perhaps installing it will be a bit trickier** as you may have to deal with UEFI partitions.

Note that those Secure Boot/UEFI things are only important if your machine came with Windows 8 by default; if you upgraded Windows 7 to Windows 8 you shouldn't have any problem related to that. Then **I'd recommend 12.04 over 12.10** because it has Long Time Support and (for me) it's more stable and fast - but you don't get some of the amazing 12.10 features like previews in the Dash or the online accounts integration.

### See also

- See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217184/whats-the-difference-between-12-04-and-12-10) for the differences between *Quantal* (12.10) and *Precise* (12.04).

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you want. I would recommend the 12.04 seeing as it has Long Term Support. 12.10 has a few extra bells and whistles. Also, if you're using a 64-bit machine be sure to get the 64-bit version. It will allow you to use your RAM more effectively.

Also be careful during the install as it is possible to overwrite your Windows 8 install. Just read all of the options and select wisely.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can use is the wubi installer 
Assuming you have the iso image, download from ubuntu website wubi installer for the corresponding distribution.

Next, since it is windows 8, one of the best things you could do is right click -> Mount Iso the particular iso file (iso image), as if it were some CD Drive.

Next run the wubi.exe and follow the steps, specify the user name and password, and give  the partition, and its size, and you are done.