# discussion regarding upgrading to 12.1 is confusing

Tags: 12.04

I use 12.04 and I install all the interim upgrades as they are offered.I see no reason to upgrade to 12.10 but when will I know 12.04 is no longer supported? I will appreciate a correction to my understanding if necessary but please be non technical

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release)

Answer (score 0):

12.04 is an LTS or long term support version. It will be supported with updates for 3 years (desktop) and 5 years (server). 12.10 is not perfect though. I had some problems and went back to 12.10.