# Why is 12.10 Quantal Quetzal only supported until 2014 while 12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin is supported until 2017?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release)

I'm not very familiar with Linux, but I'd like to know why the newer version is supported only until 2014.

What does this mean as far as upgrading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LTS means Long Term Support and the Ubuntu team releases LTS-versions every 2 years. LTS releases are defined to be enterprise focused, compatible with new hardware, and more thoroughly tested. 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS

As a home user, I would say that it does not greatly matter. If you are looking for a stable and steady ground, stay with the LTS version. If there are some functions only found in the new version that you need, use the latest version.

If you are worried about the short support, Ubuntu releases standard versions twice a year, so you could update to 12.10 and when the support is ending, update to the next version.

Answer (score 1):

LTS means Long Term Support. LTS releases come out every two years and are usually more stable than non-LTS releases.

Comment: Why do they release an LTS version and less stable versions? It doesn't make sense to me. Seems like that's more for them to manage and less users are on the same platform

Comment: Because there are a lot of us that find two whole years too long to wait for new versions of your software.