# LTS vs non LTS which is more suitable to me?

Tags: programming, lts, hosting, web-design

I am new to Ubuntu I want to know which is more suitable to me?

I want to use if for web design and hosting and for programming

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! To the extent to which this question is concrete enough to answer, it's probably [been answered here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release). Hopefully that will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.10 LTS good for you, but Ubuntu 13.04 it's now fairly stable, i think more suitable Ubuntu 12.10 for your because your newer

Comment: I read that LTS versions has security patches, does that mean non LTS are less secure? Does LTS versions got priority in updates?

Comment: No. LTS is simply stable, but may not offer you the latest features. I suggest you try both.