# Need suggestion which version of Ubuntu is suitable for my machine

Tags: installation

I have a Acer Aspire 4720Z Laptop. Is powered by Intel Pentium Dual-Core 32 BIT Mobile Processor. 1 GB RAM (have additional 1 GB but currently it is corrupted would soon replace it) and 160 GB hard drive. The laptop has Mobile Intel GL960 Express chip set. 
The Acer Aspire 4720Z notebook comprises inbuilt internal modem, wireless wi-fi, and Bluetooth connectivity. Currently have Windows 7 64 BIT OS running.

Can someone please suggest which would be the best version of Ubuntu I should install.

1) Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

2) Ubuntu 13.04

Kindly suggest.

Comment: I don't think it dupes 206407, but I've seen a similar question (best Ubuntu version given hardware specs) yesterday. To be found...

Comment: Can you provide specific details about how what you're asking is *not* covered by [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)? If not, then there's no way to answer this any better ...and it will likely still be closed as a duplicate. Maybe [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release) will help.

Answer (score 0):

In short either one.  Now as far as 13.04 goes, support on it will expire on 01/2014.  By then 13.10 will be completely out.  If you want Ubuntu 13.04, you can download it [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).  For installation instructions see [Install Ubuntu 13.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest).

Now, for 12.04LTS (Long Term Support), support on that will expire on 04/2017.  If support is what you're after, then 12.04 is the one for you.  You can download it [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).  For installation instructions see [Install Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

> So who is the latest version for? Well, if you want to be on the
>   bleeding edge, have the latest versions of all your software, and use
>   the latest features before they make it to the LTS version of Ubuntu,
>   upgrade to the every-six-month releases. If you’re a developer who
>   needs the latest versions of certain packages, you might want to
>   upgrade if getting them on the LTS version of Ubuntu is too much
>   trouble. If you use Linux because you like tinkering and experimenting
>   with the latest software — and don’t want things getting too boring
>   and predictable — upgrade to the latest release.
>
> However, you’re not missing out much by using the LTS release. You
>   don’t have to upgrade every six months anymore — Ubuntu’s LTS release
>   is well-supported and will run all the software you depend on. It’s
>   regularly updated with new hardware support and performance
>   improvements, so you shouldn’t have to upgrade to make your Wi-Fi work
>   properly or dramatically speed up your desktop.

<sup>Source:HowToGeek</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to go for Ubuntu 12.04 which is Long term support and the features are also good comparing with Windows also.

Right now am using the same version, till now I didn't faced any issues.

For your configuration,it will support for your system.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 offers you the opportunity to run Unity2D which in turn saves on CPU cycles, battery life and heat.