# Ubuntu 12.04 vs. Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 12.04, 13.04

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. And can any one please tell me what difference between Ubuntu 12 and 13 and what version of Ubuntu is better. Why?

Thanks.

Comment: Alternative dupe: [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](http://askubuntu.com/q/16366/88802)

Comment: I'm asking about 12 and 13 not 12.4 and 12.10!

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is an LTS and will be supported upto 2017. But Ubuntu  13.04 will be supported upto january 2014. However Ubuntu 13.04 comest with newer softwares and its a lot faster than Ubuntu 12.04 LTS *on newer systems*

Comment: Also: just read the [release notes](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/releasenotes) to have a list of differences introduced in every new release.

Answer (score 2):

12.04LTS stands for “long-term support.” LTS releases would be supported with security updates for years.

However, Ubuntu also have new releases every six months.  Every new release of Ubuntu offers new features.  The current release being 13.04

LTS releases will receive security updates and other bug fixes as well as hardware support improvements. The current LTS release, Ubuntu 12.04, will be supported until April 2017.

Now, a regular release like 13.04, will only be supported for nine months. Considering new versions of Ubuntu are released every six months, you’ll have three months after a new version is released to upgrade to it or you won’t receive security patches anymore.

Well, if you want to have the latest versions of all your software, and use the latest features before they make it to the LTS version of Ubuntu, upgrade to the every-six-month releases.  Now its 13.04

However, you’re not missing out much by using 12.04. It’s regularly updated with new hardware support and performance improvements.

On a personal note, I'm still using 12.04, and haven't upgraded to 13.04.

Also I would read the release notes as per gertvdijk comment above.

Comment: This information is like *everywhere* on this site. Shouldn't we close this question instead of posting new very similar answers?

Comment: I agree.  Just for the OP's comment "I'm asking about 12 and 13 not 12.4 and 12.10! "

Comment: Okay, but nothing in your answer is 13.04 specific. It's just LTS vs non-LTS.

Comment: @gertvdijk I did a minor edit, but I think a merge would be a better option. :)