# which version have better support to use in integrated services router, Ubuntu 12.04 or 13.04?

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, 32-bit

I will convert pc to router by using Ubuntu. I didn't know which version is better?

Thanks

Comment: 13.04 has the latest software but 12.04 may be more stable and is supported for longer.  My personal choice would be the LTS release but take a look at this question: [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](http://askubuntu.com/q/16366/107450)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to stick to Ubuntu for this, I recommend you use only the LTS version as @Warren Hill mentioned in his comment. You can use the minimal installation and dump all the heavy stuff along the way (minimal installation contains only the core system and downloads additional packages on the go by user's request) thus keeping it small and fast.

OpenWRT is a really great peace of software and you should at least give it a try.

Comment: i am just in research but i think i can make more feature in Ubuntu but can u help me to tell me more about openwrt ?

Comment: OpenWRT has a really nice documentation at http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/start. For a PC installation see https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=20478