# Which Ubuntu Should I Choose

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, 13.10

I am switching from Windows to Linux which is the best Linux distro? If I go for Ubuntu which version should I go for, 12.04, 13.04 or 13.10?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ubuntu 12.04.3** LTS is a long-term support release. It has continuous hardware support improvements as well as guaranteed security and support updates until April 2017.

**Ubuntu 13.10** is the new version.Ubuntu 13.10 will be supported for 9 months and includes cutting-edge new features that make your music, videos, documents and apps much easier to access.

*Ubuntu 13.10* gives you all the **latest features**, while *Ubuntu 12.04 LTS* comes with **extended support**.