# Can I check for my most recent updates on the Ubuntu website?

Tags: updates

I can't get my computer to load due to a kernel issue. Is there any way to get what version my computer is running off of online or in start up?

Comment: If my answer solve your query then select it as the answer to your question so that others can be acknowledged that your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your earlier question you should choose Ubuntu 14.04 LTS over 14.10 as it will be officially supported till april,2019 but 14.10 will be supported for 9 months only. Check the download page of [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) to download the iso of 14.04. You can also read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release) to get better idea on LTS vs Normal releases.