# 14.04 to 14.10 update gives 404 error

Tags: 14.04, 14.10, update-manager

Whenever I try to update Ubuntu to 14.10 I get the following error repeatedly:

```
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W:Failed to fetch 
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Are you sure you are on 14.04? Those repositories are for 13.04.

Answer (score 1):

[Raring](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames) (13.04, not 14.04) is not available anymore, as it's not an [LTS release](https://askubuntu.com/q/16366/1067) and it's too old.

[Change your sources](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release/91821#91821) to a newer version in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, then it should work again.

if you already got 14.04 sources in your `sources.list`, simply delete the raring entries.