# With Ubuntu LTS, what are all the support options available? (my ubuntu doesn't work after an update.)

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, lts, support

with Ubuntu LTS, what are all the support options available?

I got LTS thinking there may be some support available. Is this question and answer forum the only support option? I ask because I got an update to my lubuntu system last weekend, and that basically turned it into a brick. Is my only option now to just reinstall and hope for the best? I would love to get some support. I asked about it here last week, but no one answered. What are my best options available?

Comment: I suspect your prior question attracted little interest because it showed no evidence of prior research.  There are lots of questions on this site about booting to a blank screen.

Comment: So the key word to search for then is Booting and Blank Screen? Ok. Thanks for that. But then how about the issue of support? Is there no official support option that exists for LTS 
?

Answer (score 1):

LTS is an abbreviation for “Long Term Support”.

From [LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS)

> A new LTS version is released every 2 years. Starting with Ubuntu
>   12.04 LTS, both Desktop and Server versions will receive 5 years support. There is no extra fee for the LTS version; we make our very
>   best work available to everyone on the same free terms. Upgrades to
>   new versions of Ubuntu are and always will be free of charge.

Here, support [means](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release):

- Updates for potential security problems and bugs (not new versions of
  software)
- Availability of Commercial support contracts from Canonical (if applicable)
- Support by Landscape, Canonical's enterprise oriented server
  management tool set (if applicable)

So it is **not** a usual 'technical support' with a toll-free number and a technical support executive that you might be thinking.

If you want any help, you can always describe your problem here or in [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) and surely you will get help.

Read [this](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) to know how to ask a good question in Ask Ubuntu!