# Which Ubuntu version is better? LTS or recently released version?

Tags: release-management

Which Ubuntu version is better? LTS version or recently released version?

Comment: The answer to your question entirely depends on your personal needs. For more on LTS vs. normal releases read http://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I did the same search on askubuntu and google before installing my system around a month back. Rather than opinion I will lay down my facts;

- I used LTS versions so far 12.04 and 14 on my laptops without any
  issue and with peace of mind that I am on long term release and would
  not have to upgrade in near future.
- I recently brought a new laptop (not cutting edge by any standard). Its a Lenovo-G40. My experience with 14.04 release was not good to a point that I did install Windows in dual boot. I dont know every search I did, pointed to the fact that 15.04 is not going to be useful (since the bug fixes etc are going to be back ported in 14.04 anyways , etc etc .
- However I gave it a shot (15.04 , 64 bit version) , and I am just loving it - speed , graphics, overall comfort feeling.

Comment: Bullet points != facts.  But at least you tried....

Comment: These kind of are opinions.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently update to Ubuntu Mate 15.04 (old dual core 2.2Ghz 2Mb RAM x86 architecture). I have had a few issues with some applications, such as the Clementine music player related to codecs (not having the right ones and an easy fix). I also use the 64-bit version on a more recent laptop (dual boot with Windows 10), and no problems there. On both machines, faster speeds were noticed and I have had no stability related problems.

If you want to have a more stable version, I think LTS might be better, especially if you do not wish to update again soon (possibly). But that is the only advantage with LTS I can think of.