# Ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04, Which is better?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04

I used 14.04 for a few months, until my HDD died, and i noticed that after a updates, some sort of error always occures, being some freezes, compatibility issues, shortcuts not working, system freezing after opening LibreOffice ..etc.

I could live with those problems, but i want to know if maybe 12.04 is better.

What are the differences between them?

Is 12.04 more stable since its older, does it have better compatibility, less frequent freezes, or any other thing?

Comment: 12.04 will be supported until Spring 2017, 14.04 until 2019.

Comment: 14.04 has newer packages for some libraries and applications: http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=ubuntu .

Comment: If your machine works better with 12.04 then go for it. Try latest release first 15.04.

Comment: I guess i will install it and see how it works.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release

Comment: That about answers my question about support. Now i just need an answer about the errors and freezes

Comment: Errors and freezes will depend on the hardware your trying to run Ubuntu on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Ubuntu 12.04 with all my two PC. I haven't  errors. With Ubuntu  14.04 I had nvidia driver  issues on my Desktop pc, so I downgraded at 12.04. It is supported  until 2017,too.