# Very bad performance while browsing internet web pages (laggy page scrolling)

Tags: youtube

Very bad performance while browsing internet web pages (laggy page scrolling)
on chrome and chromium, on my hp stream13 ultrabook/laptop.
Also I can't play 60fps youtube videos !
Its very frustrating and disappointing , i'm not here to troll or make fun,
i'm here to share my own experiences.

Answer (score 0):

[HP Stream 13](https://www.laptopmag.com/reviews/laptops/hp-stream-13) has low power conscription an unfortunately low productivity Intel Celeron N3050 CPU. It is [slower than T](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare.php?cmp[]=2541&cmp[]=999) mobile series of Intel, that is over 10 years old. It also has only 2GB of RAM.

**Definately, you should use 32-bit version of the OS, and also I would prefer [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/)**, that is really lightweight and provides good performance with  CPUs, [times slower than N3050](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare.php?cmp[]=2541&cmp[]=1738). I'm sure you will play movies and browse Internet fluently, but I can't guarantee such thing for YouTube, it becomes really weight over the past few years.

Check also these topics:

- [What is the difference between Ubuntu and its derivatives?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-and-its-derivatives)
- [What version of Ubuntu should I pick?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/722333/what-version-of-ubuntu-should-i-pick)

Comment: I've bought tablet with the same CPU and amount of RAM, and curse myself hundred times since then :)