# What's the difference between Xubuntu 16.04.1 and Xubuntu 16.04.1 LTS?

Tags: lts

I've dabbled with Linux years ago and planning to give it another shot.

Is there a difference between Xubuntu 16.04.1 and Xubuntu 16.04.1 LTS?

Comment: They're the same.

Comment: Only that some people are too lazy to type in 'LTS'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release)

Answer (score 7):

No, they are exactly the same. LTS is just an acronym meaning Long Term Support. Sometimes people bother to type it, sometimes they don't. Any flavor and point release of 16.04 is LTS.

An LTS version will have support for a longer period than the interim releases (for example 16.10, 17.04, and 17.10). The next LTS release will be 18.04 (even numbered year April release)

See the [versions page in the Ubuntu help wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) to see what I mean in more detail, or read the [lts](/questions/tagged/lts) [tag wiki](https://askubuntu.com/tags/lts/info).