# ubuntu 16.10 vs 17.04

Tags: upgrade, 16.10, 17.04

I am using the 16.10 version of ubuntu, and since this version is no more supported and updated anymore. I hesitate whether do upgrading my system to the 17.04 version or stay on the 16.10. So please any feedback (fluidity of the upgrade, issues related to the newest version, stability also ...), pros and cons of both versions would be very helpful to me.

Comment: This is totally up to you. I can't wait for the newest release so I am on 17.10 since this weekend. Enjoying it very much. My choice to do so. My risk to take. At work we stick to 14.04 and have a planned schedule to move to 18.04 3 months after it releases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release)

Answer (score 2):

i'm confused - you state you are on 16.10 (non-LTS) which is out of support, then ask if you should stay on 16.04LTS ??

if you're using 16.04 LTS - I'd stay there [LTS versions are even year & april]
if you're using 16.10 - normal progression is to 17.04, 17.10 then 18.04 where you can decide to stick to LTS versions; or return to regular upgrades (18.10)

non-LTS versions usually have later apps/programs which gives you later features. The LTS releases are used for stability, but are more conservative in that they choose more-stable-older app/feature over a later version not yet proven.

this is your choice; myself I decide mostly on how often I want to bother upgrading.  (2011 was my last non-LTS version used)

Comment: It was a mistake, i meant 16.10.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would recommend not to upgrade out of a LTS version of Ubuntu like 16.10 since it can potentially break your system. However, if you are the type of user who is on the lookout for new features and enjoy fixing issues with your OS, you should go ahead with the update.

Comment: Agree, but unfortunately, I am not on an LTS version. Just wondering if the newest version worth the upgrade or not

Comment: If it is out of support it is not a matter of "worth or not worth". You should definately upgrade because you will receive no security updates anymore. If you don't want to update every half year, stick to LTS versions.