# Audio Stopped Working suddenly in 17.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 17.04

I'm running 17.04 LTS (upgraded from 16.04 a while a go).

Now and then again, audio seems to stop working for some reason. Sometimes I reboot and it starts to work again but this time it didn't. Annoyed as I am, I'm asking here to see if anyone can figure this one out.

I did `tail -f /var/log/syslog` while running `pulseaudio -k` to see what happens:

```
bluetoothd[1728]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.278 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
bluetoothd[1728]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.278 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
rtkit-daemon[1495]: Successfully made thread 4706 of process 4706 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
rtkit-daemon[1495]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
indicator-sound[2194]: volume-control-pulse.vala:735: unable to get pulse unix socket: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.PulseAudio1 was not provided by any .service 
pulseaudio[4706]: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Failed to find a working profile.
pulseaudio[4706]: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="5" name="usb-M-Audio_Keystation_61-00" card_name="alsa_card.usb-M-Audio_Keystation_61-00" atency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
bluetoothd[1728]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.354 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
bluetoothd[1728]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.354 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
rtkit-daemon[1495]: Successfully made thread 4724 of process 4724 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
rtkit-daemon[1495]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
pulseaudio[4724]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
compiz[2363]: [1:21:1204/234141.860784:ERROR:webrtcsession.cc(345)] Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: STATE_INPROGRESS
compiz[2363]: [1:21:1204/234142.874344:ERROR:webrtcsession.cc(345)] Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: STATE_INPROGRESS
compiz[2363]: [1:21:1204/234142.875896:ERROR:webrtcsession.cc(1150)] ProcessIceMessage: ICE candidates can't be added without any remote session description.
compiz[2363]: [1:1:1204/234142.875937:ERROR:rtc_peer_connection_handler.cc(1575)] Error processing ICE candidate.
unity-settings-[2205]: Unable to get default sink
unity-settings-[2205]: Unable to get default source
```

### I'm using two USB interfaces:

- Focusrite 6i6 USB Interface
- Behringer Xenyx Q502 USB Interface

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, 16.04 is an [LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release), 17.04 is not

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal commands `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0403]'`, `aplay -l`, and `pactl list short sinks`? Please also make sure that the relevant audio channels in `alsamixer` (terminal) or `gnome-alsamixer` (GUI) have their volume turned up and aren’t muted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Focusrite USB Interfaces, it can sometimes be the unit acting up.

To fix this, boot into windows and use the Mix Control app to reset the settings to factory settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting Pulseaudio configuration in home folder

- go to ~/.config/pulse/
- delete the 6 files in folder starting with same long hex number
- reboot PC or restart pulseaudio to generate clean new files

USB interfaces will often power down when not in use.

my devices usually stay on ok just by having Pulseaudio Volume Control (pavucontrol) open. pavucontrol would be tool to see more of what is happening within pulseaudio. may seem like no sound but might be going to wrong place.

There is also a module in pulseaudio configuration you can try disabling:

- open file in text editor: /etc/pulse/default.pa (need sudo/root)
- find the line `load-module module-suspend-on-idle` add # to start of line to disable command
- save edited file and reboot PC / restart pulseaudio