# Kubuntu - can't get past login screen and whiptail error

Tags: boot, kubuntu, filesystem, login-screen

I was working fine earlier today in kubuntu zesty 17.04. I tried to do a restart and then couldn't get past the login screen. It accepted the password but just brought the login screen up again.

I tried them to go into recovery mode and see if any errors appeared. The shell loaded but the filesystem was read only. First it appeared there was an error with mounting the encrypted swap partition. so I disabled mounting that temporarily but it didn't fix the issue. I loaded up a live CD and ran `fsck` too. No joy.

There is another error in the recovery shell,

> /usr/bin/env: 'node': no such file or directory

Then, on the next line:

> couldn't find whiptail, starting root shell instead of recovery menu

When I try `sudo apt-get install whiptail` it says it's already installed.

Comment: 16.10 (Yakkety) is outside support. You may find https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu as well as https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release useful.

Comment: Oops it's zesty 17.04 - forgot what version it was.

Comment: Currently supported releases are listed under [current](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve it:

1) I'd forgotten that I can enter command line from the login screen with CTRL +  ALT + F2.

2) I didn't understand the support for zesty had expired, I did a dist upgrade and everything worked fine after that. I must have accidentally turned off notifications that zesty had run out as I didn't see a message about it...