# Is Canonical Livepatch not supported on non-LTS release like Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: lts, canonical-livepatch

Last night I thought to check whether Canonical Livepatch service is working fine after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.10 from Ubuntu 18.04.
I know it was meaningless since it was working fine in Ubuntu 18.04.
But to my surprise when I ran

```
sudo canonical-livepatch status --verbose
```

I got the error:

```
2018/11/03 23:11:05 error executing status: Livepatchd error: The platform Ubuntu 18.10 is not supported. exiting.
```

I am now confused, is the problem only on my system? OR Is Canonical Livepatch service not supported on Ubuntu 18.10?

I would therefore like to request my fellow Ubuntu 18.10 users to do the check and if someone knows the reason/solution please reply to this thread.

Comment: Use LTS, @overkill! And live 5 years without pain.

Comment: well, I would like to live on the bleeding edge rather than stay secure @N0rbert.But never the less thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per [this (old) documentation](https://assets.ubuntu.com/v1/ac3aa269-DS_Canonical_Livepatch_Service_screen-AW_08.17.pdf),

> The Canonical Livepatch Service applies kernel fixes in microseconds, without restarting your Ubuntu **LTS** system.

and

> The Canonical Livepatch 
>   Service applies security critical Linux kernel patches without 
>   rebooting, keeping your Ubuntu **LTS** systems secure 
>   and compliant.

(emphasis mine)

Also as per **System Requirements** in [this Ubuntu wiki article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Livepatch), currently supported releases are Ubuntu 14.04 LTS , Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Since Ubuntu 18.10 is [**not** an LTS release](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release), it's not very surprising that it's not supported.

Comment: Thanks! And i think you are correct @pomsky.But really it does not make sense not supporting the non-lts versions for livepatch........

Comment: @overkill Actually it does - Non-LTS releases are only supported for 9 months, LTSes are supported for 5 years.  Usually the systems *needing* the LivePatch system would be systems that don't turn off ever (read: servers) that are running LTSes in most cases.