# Is using ubuntu19.04 tag safe for production environment

Tags: server, security, 18.10, docker, 19.04

Is using Ubuntu 19.04 or 18.10 tag safe for production environment as we can see that the relevant docker image gives zero vulnerabilities for it on quay.

Would having no LTS support for it cause any security issues?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is still technically a development release, having not being classified as 'ready for release' (though it's expected later today UST time).  That alone may be reason to delay installs.  *It's also still off-topic here because of it's not-yet-released status*

Comment: thanks for the reply https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/11/ubuntu-19-04-release-features it is supposed to be released on 18/04 so if its released would it be fine using it

Comment: I doubt I could provide more than what Rinzwind has already provided.  For production systems I'd opt for LTS (*long-term-support* release, then decide standard (safest) non-HWE or changing HWE kernel as needed). Only if I had specific needs that mandated a non-LTS would I opt 19.04/19.10/etc.

Comment: @guiverc release is today so not an issue :) "Only if I had specific needs that mandated a non-LTS would I opt 19.04/19.10/etc." I would then install that version on the LTS myself. (like mysql 8 if you must have json object in older Ubuntu)

Comment: actually our requirement is that we would be using ubuntu as the base image and want all the vulneribilities to be taken down to nulll which the 19.04/18.10 is offering as we can see zero vulneribilities on quay but for 18.04 it is showing vulneribilities

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release)

Answer (score 2):

> Would having no lts support for it cause any security issues.

No. LTS gets the same security and hardware upgrades (HWE) as the not-LTS. 18.04 -> 18.10 = 18.04.1-> 19.04 = 18.4.2 -> 19.10 = 18.4.3 -> 20.4 = 18.4.4 -> 20.10 = 18.4.5 (in regards to the hardware support).

LTS is about stability. You depend on the software versions that got releases at the time + security updates. That makes an LTS stable and secure. Rock solid even and that is what you want as a company: people need to be using the software and not wait for a bug to be solved.

If you want to use 19.04 or 18.10 for production you need to accept you will be upgrading every 6 months. Plan for it and it will be fine. But the LTS makes that upgrade once every 5 years so is a lot less disturbing.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply ,apart from upgrading would there be any security concers on using it

Comment: One thing to take note of is changes between LTS: we went from init to upstart to systemd. We started using snaps. But that is more a usability issue and not security.

Comment: 18.04 LTS is really bad. The default gnome desktop is very laggy than 18.10 and 16.04 LTS. 16.04 was best for me but 18.10 has great ui.

Answer (score 0):

> Would having no lts support for it cause any security issues.

**Yes, maybe.**

I would argue that LTS is not only more stable, but also **more secure**. Every *known* vulnerability is fixed in either LTS and non-LTS, there is no difference, but Non-LTS Ubuntu has newer software packages with new features that are not in use for that long, thus not tested as much.