# I've got Windows 10 Pro and want to install Ubuntu on Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, windows, distro-recommendation

Which Distro I should use if I've got Intel Core i5-4300U CPU x64? 
Please, give certain variants, which you know will be installed for sure.

Comment: It depends on how much CPU and RAM you want the guest OS to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) and [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to use the GUI environment, I would suggest 18.04 as it is the LTS (Long Term Support) version of the OS. You will receive 5 years of updates and security patches to the OS before it is considered "deprecated", however, you will continue to receive package updates going forward as long as they work under the LTS distribution.

If you're looking for the flashy/new GUI, tools, and environment 19.04 is fine as well, however, you only get updates/security patches to the OS until January 2020.

If you're looking for the server version, try to stick with the LTS versions.