# What is the current status for Ubuntu 19 LTS?

Tags: 19.04

I'm used to installing LTS versions. It seems that 19.04 is not LTS, but it is said in many places that it improves desktop performance and 18 is getting old. Is 19 really not planned for LTS? What would be the expected future upgrade path from version 19.04 forward?

Comment: ***Upgrade path from 19.04 forward***: 19.04→19.10→20.04 where 20.04 will be LTS

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 19 either; there is Ubuntu Core 18 but it's intended for IoT appliance devices.  Standard Ubuntu releases are *yy.mm* in format because they are release twice per year (April & October), specialist releases like Ubuntu Core 18 which only have a single release in a year only use *yy* format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release) and [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/q/34430/)

Comment: Looks like 19.04 is supported "until January 2020" FWIW...

Comment: That's before a new LTS is out isn't it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LTS Releases are published every two years in April, and it is released on even years (e.g. **2016 → 2018 → 2020**).

19.04 is currently latest stable version of Ubuntu, as it was released on **2019**, so it do not receive long term support as opposed of 18.04.

The future upgrade path to 19.04 would be: 19.04 → 19.10 → 20.04, with 20.04 being LTS releases once again.

For more details https://www.ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle

Answer (score 2):

LTS are expected every 2 years. So next LTS will be the 20.04. Intermediate versions could (and usually do) sport some improvements but they usually are less tested. So your mileage may vary. I suggest you to stay with the LTS. You you want to see how it looks 19.04 just try a boot from a USB Flash disk without installing, so you can see by yourself if it is worth the change.

Comment: Not really, because I'm not looking for just a desktop for media and youtube. I use it as a development machine, so you can't develop off a flash disk without setting it up laboriously with all of your toolchains. But thanks none the same.

Comment: ok then, but it's easy to check the versions of the libraries you need for your task from the command line, as simple as typing: apt show search name_of_the_lib and then apt show name_of_the_lib to check it's version...